# Identification about a manga with a VR game that results in "IRL" gender changes

Tags: trans-trans

So i remember once reading a mange where theres is an online VR game. Two classmates play it without knowing that either plays it, Both of them hate eachother in real life but in game are very close.
Both of them play the opposite genders.
The girl playing as a male and vice versa.
One day they get stuck in the game due to a "bug" and i believe one of them turns into the gender they were in the game.

Any help would be appreciated.

To further add, The male character is a so called "loner"

Thank you for your time.

Edit: I remember that when the male character was later "attacked" in the manga. his game persona took over his real life body for a little while.
2nd Edit: Found it, Check answers.

Comment: Are you thinking of [1/2 Prince](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=27841)?

Comment: @ ʞɹɐzǝɹ Sadly no.

Answer (score 3):

Found it, [**Trans Trans**](http://myanimelist.net/manga/61561/Trans_Trans) by Ruen Rouga. For some odd reason it is simply listed under RUEN Rouga however.

> A girl playing a male character in a video game falls in love with a female character in the virtual world while unaware the player is actually a boy. Meanwhile strange distortions begin to happen in the real world...

[image: pic]

Comment: Nice that you managed to find the answer! Might you be able to include a little information about the manga, in case someone else is interested in it? (There is a meta post on how to answer identification requests, which I unfortunately can't easily link to while on mobile.)